# How is the rank earned at the end of a level calculated?

Tags: pokemon-shuffle

I assumed that is was based on score, but then I beat a level in less moves but with a lower score and received a higher rank. If the rank is based on remaining moves, just like the pokemon's catchability, what is the purpose of receiving a score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Shuffle#Ranks):

> The rank the player earns is determined by **the number of moves or
>   amount of time the player has remaining**, and the total number of
>   moves or amount of time the player started the stage with.
>
> For most move-limited stages, if the number of moves remaining upon
>   competition of the stage is greater than or equal to half the total
>   number of moves they started with (rounded down), the player will be
>   awarded an S-rank. While the purchase of a +5 Moves does not affect
>   catch percentages, it does affect rank. For most timed stages, if the
>   amount of time remaining upon competition of the stage is greater than
>   or equal to half the total amount of time they started with (rounded
>   down), the player will be awarded an S-rank.
>
> - All Competitive Stages and Stage 149: Haxorus will always grant an S-rank upon competition, regardless of performance. Meowth's Coin
>     Mania also shares this trait.
> - Expert stages are unlocked depending on total number of S-ranks the player has on main stages. Ranks on expert and special stages have no
>     impact on gameplay.
>
> The ranks below S are A, B, and C, respectively. Remaining move
>   numbers for each rank are typically arbitrary, as on many stages with
>   low starting moves it can be impossible to get a B or C rank. Ranks
>   below S serve no functional value, regardless, and do not contribute
>   to the unlocking of extra stages.

Comment: And regarding the purpose of the score, as *Jerry* wrote, it's just for online competitions.

Answer (score 1):

The rank is based on the number of moves left after dealing enough damage to the Pokemon you are playing against. I take it as a rule of thumb for, the regular levels, that **half** the given moves give S rank (rounded up if the moves is odd; e.g. if you have 15 moves, using 8 moves or lower and complete the stage gives you S), and similar for time based levels, using **half** the given time will give you S.

The score on regular levels might not mean much to the player. But this score can be used in online competitions. The last one as of today was a timed level with 1 minute to get a highest score against MegaCharizard Y and the players are ranked based off their scores, which then is used to determine who gets prizes and who don't.